# Creating a plot using matplotlib using dataframes containing two lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am using matplotlib for the very first time and trying to learn dataframes.

Now , In my code I have two lists.I have created a dataframe seperately for those two lists.
I intend to create a step plot using those lists.

```
energy_price = [33.28, 30.00, 29.15, 28.49, 34.66, 50.01,  #14 sept nord pool day ahead SE1
               71.52, 77.94, 81.97, 87.90, 92.76, 94.98,
               92.31, 90.03, 90.09, 87.44, 85.37, 79.97,
               79.92, 77.83, 76.28, 65.06, 53.07, 34.16]
rtn_t0=15

price_energy = []
for price in energy_price:
    price_energy = price_energy + [int(price)] * int(60 / rtn_t0) #prices for 96 time slots


time1 = list()

for x in range(1,int(num_t + 1)):
    time1.append(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(price_energy)
df = pd.DataFrame(time1)
```

How do I create a step plot with time1 on x-axis & price_energy on y axis?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [step plot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-step-demo-py) has an example:

```py
. . .

time1 = [x for x in range(0, len(price_energy), 1)]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.step(time1, price_energy)
plt.xticks([x for x in range(0, len(price_energy), 5)])
plt.ylabel("Electricity Costs")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Azhar, Thanks for replying. How to get x axis in step of 5 ? like 0,5,10,15,.......in the x axis instead of the 20 step size, I mean value of price_energy at 0, price_energy at 1.....

Comment: Do you mean this: `time1 = [x for x in range(0, len(price_energy), 5)]`?

Comment: Hi Azhar, I edited the question & added an image. This kind of stepsize in x axis I intend to have.

Comment: Updated the solution as per the updated question.

Comment: Hi @Azhar , thanks a lot! That totally makes sense. However do you think problem was in figure size?

Answer (score 0):

There in your code you assign `df` two times, the second time overwrites the first. The proper way should be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time1': time1,
                   'price_energy': price_energy})
```

Then plot the step plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.step(x='time1', y='price_energy', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi n Nikita , thanks for answering. Is it possible to have a step of 5 in the x axis, I mean 0,5,10,15,....As the current plot has the step of 20

Comment: If you intend to just change the x-axis tick interval you can first import numpy if you haven't: `import numpy as np` and then after the step plot code add: `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df['time1'])+1, 5))`

Comment: Hi Nikita, As you can see I tried to do that `df = pd.DataFrame({'time1': time1,
                   'price_energy': price_energy})

plt.step(x='time1', y='price_energy', data=df)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df['time1'])+1, 5))
plt.show()` But that doesnt let me have the plot as I mentioned in the question., Would you please help me in whats the issue? I am getting the plot that I just attached in the question, but not as what I intend to get.

Comment: @MargiShah what if you change `rtn_t0` to 12 in your code, if it's not crucial to your calculations?

Comment: Hi Nikita, I cant because my entire code is related to it. If you can just observe the above two plots, which I plotted and which actually should be, What can be the issue?

Comment: See, it seems to me that you're trying to place 96 time slots, thus 96 steps (it is hardcoded in your calculations) on a 5 step scale

Comment: However, it seems to me that regarding x-tick intervals the two plots are identical. What is very much different is y-axis values, therefore if you assume to make these plots to look exactly the same you might wanna look into how `price_energy` is calculated.